# Envelopes: listStatusChanges does not return Envelopes with is21CFRPart11

Tags: docusignapi

Calling the DocuSign API endpoint, Envelopes: listStatusChanges:

```
GET /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes
```

does not return [Envelopes](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatusChanges#Envelopes) with the `is21CFRPart11` property. How do I get this property using [Envelopes: listStatusChanges](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatusChanges).

Comment: I'm confused about which API you are using and what is the issue.
Are you saying you don't see the is21CFRPart11 property or you don't see the envelopes themselves? 
Can you try to use this API ?https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/get
It should return this property

Comment: does your account you use for this app have CFRPart11 configured?

Comment: Hi. I don't see the `is21CFRPart11` for listStatusChanges property. GetEnvelope for a single envelope does return it but listStatusChanges does not.

Comment: yes, that may be a bug. Either in the API, or, more likely, in the documentation

Comment: Hi @InbarGazit. The reason I am asking this question is that https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Folders/Folders/search does return a list of folder items with `is21CFRPart11` property. However, the documentation also says that this method is depreacted in v2.1, use Envelopes::listStatusChanges instead. So if Envelopes: listStatusChanges is supposed to be a replacement for Folders: search, shouldn't it have the same functionality, at the least?

Comment: you bring a good point Rokcy, I'm still trying to get answers for you, there's a bug here somewhere, potentially in the documentation.

Comment: BTW, I'm sure you know this, but you could mix and match v2 and v2.1 API calls in your app. If that helps...

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a documentation bug. I'm going to confirm this, but as a workaround for now you can use the GetEnvelope API and it does returns the value for isCFRPart11